# How should I tackle playing a big chord like this f# a d a

Tags: piano

[image]How should I play the 2nd chord. I can just about reach it but it’s a bit uncomfortable to play.

Answer (score 5):

Rachmaninoff did not always take lesser mortals into account in his piano writing!

Richard's answer discusses rolling the chord.  I will offer another opinion and option, pick according to your taste.

You can omit a note.  I would rather do this than roll the chord, as it will preserve the pizzicato character of the accompaniment.  Rolling the chord, even if done very fluently and rapidly, can draw attention to it.  This works against the music, which has been written to draw the ear to the pizzicato-like high As in the right hand.

The least important note in the chord is the lower A.  If you can almost play the chord as written, it might be possible without that note, depending on the shape of your hand.  Omitting the upper A is also possible.  Consider these facts: A is tripled here; the music is presto pianissimo; this is the least prominent part of the texture; and Rachmaninoff's work is a transcription already. In the circumstances, I think you have carte blanche, and revoicing the chord as I suggest makes nearly no difference.

Comment: If you're going to omit a note because the chord is too widely spaced, you should omit the *upper* a. There are already two a notes sounding, the upper a sounded immediately before, the f sharp is much more important to the harmony, and you avoid overstretching your hand for very little effect.

Comment: The lower A sounded immediately before as well. It's up to the individual whether the hand is overstretched.  For example, the chord without the lower A is easy for me, but awkward with the lower A added.  Omitting the upper A changes the sound a little more, as it's in a brighter register.  I find the third it forms with the semiquaver C# is more prominent than that the lower A forms with F#.  It's of course all a matter of opinion!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to roll this chord.

By "roll," I mean that you very quickly arpeggiate it; begin with the low F♯ and then play each pitch in ascending order. You'll need to move your arm up the keyboard as you do it so that you can end up hitting that high A.

There are some disagreements on how the roll should relate to the beat. Should the roll *begin* on the beat, or should it start *before* the beat? Experiment to see which you like best, but in my experience, beginning the roll slightly *before* the beat (so that the high A occurs right on beat 2) is most common.

In theory, you could hit the high A in the left hand with your right hand, but it's next to impossible at the tempo this piece demands. You're better off rolling it.